# Use of didBeginDragging

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to use the function didBeginDragging to execute code when an user drag a marker on a map.
I use this code but It's doesn't work...

```
extension ViewController: GMSMapViewDelegate{

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didBeginDragging marker: GMSMarker) {
        print("didBeginDragging")
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didDrag marker: GMSMarker) {
        print("didDrag")
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didEndDragging marker: GMSMarker) {
        print("didEndDragging")
    }
}
```

I have the version 2.0.1 of GoogleMapsSDK, it is the problem ?

Do you have an idea to solve my problem ?
Thanks

Comment: Did you set the map view's delegate?

Comment: That's right..
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the delegate of the map view, just implementing the delegate won't work.